# CMake subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake and I want to try and make it so I have a subdirectory for it rather than files scattered through my project or the root of it.

I have a directory layout of `project/cmake/CMakeLists.txt` and `project/bin` and `project/source`, so people can easily remove the CMake stuff if they want to. My only problem is that there probably is a way to do this that I don't know of. Currently it generates a bunch of rubbish including a `project/cmake/bin/obtap.dir/home/jookia/Programming/obtap/source` folder.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(obtap)
add_definitions(-g -Wall)
add_executable(../bin/obtap ../source/main.cpp)
```

It compiles fine, it outputs the right directories. But my problems are this:
Is there a way to remove `project/cmake/bin` directory and optionally, is there a way to not have all the CMake stuff and instead just generate a makefile so I have two files, CMakeLists.txt and Makefile?

Comment: What do you mean by removing the bin directory? Why `rm -fr project/cmake/bin` doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in the [CMake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F), the generated Makefiles contains full path to libraries and source code, so there is no easy way to distribute a build tree generated by CMake.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want should be the so called **out of source build**, which can be achieved by generating intermediate files in a separate directory by **running cmake in a dedicated directory**, for your case, you can try below commands:

```
mkdir -p project/bld/
cd project/bld/
cmake project/cmake
```

Now you get all the CMake stuffs generated in the *project/bld* directory and whenever you want to remove all those things, just run:

```
rm -fr project/bld/
```

You can even get several different profiles by setting up different build trees.

One issue may arise if you want to control the generated executable output path such that it's not hidden in the deeply nested cmake intermediate binary tree; the answer is you can set the variable **CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR** to customise the executable output absolute path, or just use `cmake -E` and `add_custom_command` command to copy the executable out.